# Trying to model a system of differential equations for outbreaks

Tags: differential-equations

I have this SEIR system of differential equations for modeling pandemics

```
p=10 (*total population*)
b=0.9 (*infection rate*)
d=0.5 (*rate at which infected become contagious*)
y=0.2 (*death/remove rate*)
outbreak = {s'[t] == -b*s[t]*i[t]/p, 
                e'[t] == b*s[t]*i[t]/p - d*e[t], 
                i'[t] == d*e[t] - y*i[t], 
                r'[t] == y*i[t],
                p == s[t] + e[t] + i[t] + r[t]}
initialconditions = {s[0] = p, e[0] = 1, i[0] = 0, r[0] = 0, s'[0] = 0, e'[0] = 0, i'[0] = 0, r'[0] = 0}
```

where `p`(population size), `b`(infection rate), `d`(contagious rate), **y**(removal rate) are constants

An example of a similar can be found here, that I'm trying to reproduce.

http://www.public.asu.edu/~hnesse/classes/seir.html

I just can't figure out how to use the `NDSolve` command as I keep throwing up errors.

Edit:
I have this now

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
outbreak = {s'[t] == -b*s[t]*i[t]/p, e'[t] == b*s[t]*i[t]/p - d*e[t], 
   i'[t] == d*e[t] - y*i[t], r'[t] == y*i[t], 
   p == s[t] + e[t] + i[t] + r[t]};
initialconditions = {s[0] == p, e[0] == 1, i[0] == 0, r[0] == 0, 
   s'[0] == 0, e'[0] == 0, i'[0] == 0, r'[0] == 0};
p = 10; (*total population*)
b = 0.9 ;(*infection rate*)
d = 0.5; (*rate at which infected become contagious*)
y = 0.2 ;(*death/remove rate*)
NDSolve[Join[outbreak, initialconditions], {s[t], e[t], i[t], 
  r[t]}, {t, 0, 60}]
```

But it gives the error There are fewer dependent variables, {e[t],i[t],r[t],s[t]}, than equations, so the system is overdetermined. >>

Comment: in your initial conditions, you should have `==` instead of `=`.  Make sure you quit your Mathematica session before trying to run it again.

Comment: @EricBrown I end up with this 
NDSolve[Join[outbreak, initialconditions], {s[t], e[t], i[t], 
  r[t]}, {t, 0, 60}] and it says the error comes up that there are fewer dependant variables than equations so the system is overdetermined

Comment: I think you're closer, not sure if your Initial Value Problem (IVP), e.g. s[0]==p needs the derivatives specified too.

Comment: I posted my new code that seems to be closer, but still throws up the fewer dependent variables so the system is over determined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're very close.  I reformatted the code a bit, and removed the conservation equation for `p[t]`.

```
p = 10 (*total population*)
b = 0.9 (*infection rate*)
d = 0.5 (*rate at which infected become contagious*)
y = 0.2 (*death/remove rate*)

outbreak = {
  s'[t] == -b*s[t]*i[t]/p,
  e'[t] == b*s[t]*i[t]/p - d*e[t],
  i'[t] == d*e[t] - y*i[t],
  r'[t] == y*i[t]
 }
initialconditions = {
  s[0] == p,
  e[0] == 1,
  i[0] == 0,
  r[0] == 0
}

soln = Last@NDSolve[
   {
    outbreak,
    initialconditions
   },
   {s[t], e[t], i[t], r[t]}
   , {t, 0, 60}]
```

[image: soln]

```
Plot[
 s[t] /. soln
 , {t, 0, 60}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "s(t)"]
```

[image: s(t)]

I would have to check this carefully, but I think that Mathematica's ODE integrator is capable of maintaining constant "density" without resorting to an additional variable for `p[t]`.  Specifying this additional equation will lead to an overdetermined system, unless you can put it in the variable list to be solved.

Also, for IVP problems of this type, only `s[0]` or `s'[0]` need to be specified, and for SEIR I suspect that we know `s[0]` much more often than the derivatives. (Furthermore, at $t=0$, the derivatives are not 0! It will change straight away.)

Good luck! Mathematica is great for solving ODEs found in disease modeling.

Comment: Oh this is just perfect! Yea, I have a project in which my group has to model an Ebola outbreak, and have to consider various factors to control an outbreak. I just couldn't get the code to work! Thanks!

Comment: @xCanaan You're welcome.  For a lark, you might want to plot `p[t]` (which you can get by summing the solutions $s(t) + e(t) + i(t) + r(t)$ just to make sure that the quantity is conserved.  It should (numerically) be a horizontal line.  Significant deviations would indicate that you need to change methods, e.g. use Method -> "BDF"  For some particular parameters and infectious disease models, the equations are remarkably stiff.

Comment: I seem to get `p[t]=11` using this method.  (It's constant up to machine precision.)  This is caused by the ICs `s[0]==p, e[0]==1`.  Taking `s[0]==p-1` works.